# Cannot access neo4j web interface when using Jetty 8

Tags: java, neo4j, jetty-8

Everything works fine when I deployed using Tomcat 7.  http://localhost:7474/browser can be showed successfully(also webadmin). Using Neo4j 2.1.7

But when changed to deploy my application into Jetty 8 (actually in solr's Jetty 8.1.10), everything worked fine (my web application can get data from embedded neo4j database correctly) except accessing /browser and /webadmin.

error below was showed instead:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /browser/. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendData(DefaultServlet.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:513)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:566)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

By the way, I unpacked neo4j-browser-2.1.7.jar and neo4j-server-2.1.7-static-web.jar and when I started jetty I saw the message which showed everything seemed ok:

```
    2015-05-29 11:22:18 WARN  ContextHandler:1302 - o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@9ed9f8{/,null,null} contextPath ends with /
    2015-05-29 11:22:18 WARN  ContextHandler:1308 - Empty contextPath
    2015-05-29 11:22:18 INFO  Server:284 - jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
    2015-05-29 11:22:18 INFO  ContextHandler:734 - Started o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@167791b{/,null,AVAILABLE}
    2015-05-29 11:22:18 INFO  ContextHandler:734 - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@323ee8{/webadmin,file:/C:/superbase/core/relation-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/webadmin-html/,AVAILABLE}
    5 29, 2015 11:22:18  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
    INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM
    2015-05-29 11:22:19 INFO  ContextHandler:734 - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@e478d0{/db/manage,null,AVAILABLE}
    5 29, 2015 11:22:19  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
    INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM
    2015-05-29 11:22:19 INFO  ContextHandler:734 - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e2c341{/db/data,null,AVAILABLE}
    2015-05-29 11:22:19 INFO  ContextHandler:734 - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1e099db{/browser,file:/C:/superbase/core/relation-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/browser/,AVAILABLE}
    5 29, 2015 11:22:19  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
    INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM
    2015-05-29 11:22:19 INFO  ContextHandler:734 - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@9ed9f8{/,null,AVAILABLE}
    2015-05-29 11:22:19 INFO  ServerConnector:265 - Started ServerConnector@14aa09f{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:7474}
    13920 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  ? FrameworkServlet dispatcher: initialization completed in 8316 ms
```

**UPDATE**
Test in pure jetty 8.1 but failed as the same.

full debug log when accessing /browser:

```
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector$Accept@d552ab
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Selector loop woken up from select, 0/0 selected
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Running change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector$Accept@d552ab
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG AbstractEndPoint:64 - onOpen SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{null}{io=0,kio=0,kro=0}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG IdleTimeout:64 - SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{null}{io=0,kio=0,kro=0} idle timeout check, elapsed: 8 ms, remaining: 29992 ms
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpConnection:64 - New HTTP Connection HttpConnection@1f9fdda{IDLE},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of 0}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG AbstractConnection:64 - onOpen HttpConnection@1f9fdda{IDLE},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of 0}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG AbstractConnection:64 - fillInterested HttpConnection@1f9fdda{IDLE},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of 0}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectChannelEndPoint:64 - Local interests updated 0 -> 1 for SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{true,AC.ExReadCB@1f9fdda},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of 0}}{io=1,kio=0,kro=0}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Created SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{true,AC.ExReadCB@1f9fdda},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of 0}}{io=1,kio=0,kro=0}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Running change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$1@1892bd6
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectChannelEndPoint:64 - Key interests updated 0 -> 1
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Selector loop waiting on select
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Selector loop woken up from select, 1/1 selected
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectChannelEndPoint:64 - Key interests updated 1 -> 0
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectChannelEndPoint:64 - Local interests updated 1 -> 0 for SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{true,AC.ExReadCB@1f9fdda},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of 0}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Running change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$1@1892bd6
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG QueuedThreadPool:64 - qtp2906178{STARTED,4<=5<=40,i=1,q=0} dispatched AC.ExReadCB@1f9fdda
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Selector loop waiting on select
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpConnection:64 - HttpConnection@1f9fdda{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of 0} onFillable org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState@4456b0@IDLE,initial
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ChannelEndPoint:64 - filled 410 SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of 0}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpConnection:64 - HttpConnection@1f9fdda{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of 0} filled 410
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - START --> SPACE1
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - SPACE1 --> URI
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - URI --> SPACE2
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - SPACE2 --> REQUEST_VERSION
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - REQUEST_VERSION --> HEADER
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER --> HEADER_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_VALUE --> HEADER_IN_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_IN_VALUE --> HEADER
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER --> HEADER_IN_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_IN_VALUE --> HEADER
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER --> HEADER_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_VALUE --> HEADER_IN_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_IN_VALUE --> HEADER
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER --> HEADER_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_VALUE --> HEADER_IN_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_IN_VALUE --> HEADER
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER --> HEADER_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_VALUE --> HEADER_IN_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_IN_VALUE --> HEADER
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER --> HEADER_IN_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_IN_VALUE --> HEADER
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER --> HEADER_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_VALUE --> HEADER_IN_VALUE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER_IN_VALUE --> HEADER
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - HEADER --> END
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpConnection:64 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input@1dd69ad{HttpChannelOverHttp@cdf0a6{r=1,a=IDLE,uri=-},HttpConnection@1f9fdda{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of 0}} shutdown
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpChannel:64 - HttpChannelOverHttp@cdf0a6{r=1,a=IDLE,uri=-} handle enter
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG Server:64 - REQUEST /browser/ on HttpChannelOverHttp@cdf0a6{r=1,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/browser/}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ContextHandler:64 - scope null||/browser/ @ o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@12f0484{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ContextHandler:64 - context=||/browser/ @ o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@12f0484{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ContextHandler:64 - scope null||/browser/ @ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1c6488a{/webadmin,file:/C:/superbase/core/relation-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/webadmin-html/,AVAILABLE}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ContextHandler:64 - scope null||/browser/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@19bdf5f{/db/manage,null,AVAILABLE}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ContextHandler:64 - scope null||/browser/ @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1fbc0b4{/db/data,null,AVAILABLE}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ContextHandler:64 - scope null||/browser/ @ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1ab04cf{/browser,file:/C:/superbase/core/relation-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/browser/,AVAILABLE}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ContextHandler:64 - context=/browser||/ @ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1ab04cf{/browser,file:/C:/superbase/core/relation-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/browser/,AVAILABLE}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG session:64 - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@1b95566
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG session:64 - session=null
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ServletHandler:64 - servlet /browser|/|null -> default@5c13d641==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet,0,true
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ServletHandler:64 - chain=null
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ContextHandler:64 - scope /browser||/browser/index.html @ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1ab04cf{/browser,file:/C:/superbase/core/relation-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/browser/,AVAILABLE}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ContextHandler:64 - context=/browser||/index.html @ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1ab04cf{/browser,file:/C:/superbase/core/relation-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/browser/,AVAILABLE}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG session:64 - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@1b95566
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG session:64 - session=null
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ServletHandler:64 - servlet /browser|/index.html|null -> default@5c13d641==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet,0,true
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ServletHandler:64 - chain=null
2015-05-29 13:58:28 WARN  ServletHandler:557 - /browser/
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendData(DefaultServlet.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:513)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:566)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ServletHandler:64 - (GET /browser/)@12981946 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@c616ba
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpConnection:64 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$CommitCallback@193a9f0 generate: NEED_HEADER (null,[p=0,l=3344,c=4096,r=3344],true)@START
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpConnection:64 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$CommitCallback@193a9f0 generate: FLUSH ([p=0,l=179,c=20480,r=179],[p=0,l=3344,c=4096,r=3344],true)@COMPLETING
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG WriteFlusher:64 - write: WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE} [HeapByteBuffer@17cad6c[p=0,l=179,c=20480,r=179]={<<<HTTP/1.1 500 Serv....v20130312)||||>>>?????????????????...???????????????},HeapByteBuffer@5d8f3d[p=0,l=3344,c=4096,r=3344]={<<<<html>|<head>|<me.../body>|</html>|>>>?????????????????...???????????????}]
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG WriteFlusher:64 - update WriteFlusher@18e2e18{WRITING}:IDLE-->WRITING
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ChannelEndPoint:64 - flushed 3523 SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{WRITING},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=COMPLETING},p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of 0}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG WriteFlusher:64 - flushed true
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG WriteFlusher:64 - update WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE}:WRITING-->IDLE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpConnection:64 - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$CommitCallback@193a9f0 generate: DONE ([p=179,l=179,c=20480,r=0],[p=3344,l=3344,c=4096,r=0],true)@END
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG Server:64 - RESPONSE /browser/  500 handled=true
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - reset HttpParser{s=END,0 of 0}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpParser:64 - END --> START
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpChannel:64 - HttpChannelOverHttp@cdf0a6{r=1,a=IDLE,uri=-} handle exit, result COMPLETE
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ChannelEndPoint:64 - filled 0 SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG ChannelEndPoint:64 - filled 0 SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG HttpConnection:64 - HttpConnection@1f9fdda{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1} filled 0
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG AbstractConnection:64 - fillInterested HttpConnection@1f9fdda{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectChannelEndPoint:64 - Local interests updated 0 -> 1 for SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{true,AC.ExReadCB@1f9fdda},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=1,kio=0,kro=1}
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$1@1892bd6
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Selector loop woken up from select, 0/1 selected
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Running change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$1@1892bd6
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectChannelEndPoint:64 - Key interests updated 0 -> 1
2015-05-29 13:58:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Selector loop waiting on select
2015-05-29 13:58:58 DEBUG IdleTimeout:64 - SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{true,AC.ExReadCB@1f9fdda},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 29836 ms, remaining: 164 ms
2015-05-29 13:58:58 DEBUG IdleTimeout:64 - SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{true,AC.ExReadCB@1f9fdda},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 30002 ms, remaining: -2 ms
2015-05-29 13:58:58 DEBUG IdleTimeout:64 - SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{true,AC.ExReadCB@1f9fdda},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout expired
2015-05-29 13:58:58 DEBUG AbstractConnection:64 - HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1} onFillInterestedFailed java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30002/30000 ms
2015-05-29 13:58:58 DEBUG ChannelEndPoint:64 - oshut SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}
2015-05-29 13:58:58 DEBUG WriteFlusher:64 - failed: WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE} java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30002/30000 ms
2015-05-29 13:59:06 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Selector loop woken up from select, 1/1 selected
2015-05-29 13:59:06 DEBUG SelectChannelEndPoint:64 - Key interests updated 1 -> 0
2015-05-29 13:59:06 DEBUG SelectChannelEndPoint:64 - Local interests updated 1 -> 0 for SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=true,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
2015-05-29 13:59:06 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Running change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$1@1892bd6
2015-05-29 13:59:06 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Selector loop waiting on select
2015-05-29 13:59:28 DEBUG IdleTimeout:64 - SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=true,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 30002 ms, remaining: -2 ms
2015-05-29 13:59:28 DEBUG IdleTimeout:64 - SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=true,is=false,os=true,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1} idle timeout expired
2015-05-29 13:59:28 DEBUG WriteFlusher:64 - failed: WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE} java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30002/30000 ms
2015-05-29 13:59:28 DEBUG ChannelEndPoint:64 - close SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=false,is=false,os=true,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
2015-05-29 13:59:28 DEBUG SelectorManager:64 - Destroyed SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=false,is=true,os=true,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=0,kio=-1,kro=-1}
2015-05-29 13:59:28 DEBUG AbstractConnection:64 - onClose HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}
2015-05-29 13:59:28 DEBUG AbstractEndPoint:64 - onClose SelectChannelEndPoint@7328af{/127.0.0.1:12167<r-l>/127.0.0.1:7474,o=false,is=true,os=true,fi=FillInterest@73ff8b{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e2e18{IDLE},it=30000}{HttpConnection@1f9fdda{INTERESTED},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}}{io=0,kio=-1,kro=-1}
```

Comment: I think you should detail how you run neo4j from **within** your tomcat/jetty deployment if it is a version conflict there is little that we can do. What do you need / use browser for?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Using **WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper** in class Neo4jDbConfig which extends Neo4jConfigration ,just like this neoServerBootstrapper = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper(api, config);neoServerBootstrapper.start();   And  using browser/webAdmin for viewing data stored as data manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j's server component internally uses Jetty 9.0.5 by itself. Since you wanna run Neo4j inside a Jetty8 via WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper, you most likely have both, jetty 8 and jetty 9 jars on your classpath.

In this case class loading order is not deterministic and this might be the root cause for the issue you're seeing. Either use Jetty 9.0.5 for your container as well or use a clean classloader separation to allow Jetty 8 and 9 coexisting friendly with each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried using Jetty 9.2 and it works fine.